# how do I add a word to a list with user input

Tags: swift

hello this app takes the user input in a textfield and when a button is pressed it displays the word on the screen. when I try to add a new word to the list my old entry gets deleted by the new one. How can I not delete stuff and just keep all of my data.. thanks !

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textLabel.becomeFirstResponder()
    
}


@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    
    label.text = textLabel.text
    textLabel.text = ""
    
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    textLabel.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to solve this is to have a data source that holds the lists of words rather than trying to move the the word directly from one UI component to another. For this we can either use a String property or an Array (of String) property. I will use an array.

```
var words = [String]()
```

Then use this in your `button` function

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    //Check that the user has actually entered something otherwise exit
    guard let newWord = textLabel.text, !newWord.isEmpty else { return }

    //Add the new word to the data source
    words.append(newWord)

    //Generate a new list of words from the data source
    label.text = words.joined(separator: ", ")

    textLabel.text = ""  
}
```

Comment: because I thought it was going to work I get an error with the line words.append(newWord) can u help me please

Comment: sorry I get an error at the line words.joined (operator) it says cannot find separator in scope

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 different manners.

1: You store the result in an array like:

```
words.append(textLabel.text)
```

and then:`label.text = words.joined(by: ", ")`

2: add it directly

```
label.text = label.text + ", " + textLabel.text
```

Comment: its not working for me method 1 or 2 :( can u show me where in the code I'm supposed to paste this